# Haskell : difficulty with fromList

Tags: haskell

```
testing4 = Map.fromList
          (fmap (\(userid,email)->( User {userId=userid,userEmail=email},( (t2 userid), (t3 userid)   ))) userList)
          where
          t2 userid= fmap (\(_,ppid,pact,pclas,pdes)-> Permission {permissionId=ppid,permissionAction=pact,permissionClass=pclas,permissionDescripton=pdes}
                ) (DL.filter (\(puid,_,_,_,_)-> userid == puid) individualPermissions)

          t3 userid =DL.nub $ fmap (\(_,rid,_)->
                                Map.fromList ( 
                                    fmap (\ (_,rrid,rrname) -> 
                                                    (Role {roleId=rrid,roleName=rrname},
                                                        fmap (\(_,_,ppid1,pact1,pclas1,pdes1)-> 
                                                                    Permission{permissionId=ppid1,permissionAction=pact1,permissionClass=pclas1,permissionDescripton=pdes1})
                                                                                    (DL.filter (\(plUID,plRID,_,_,_,_)-> plUID == userid && plRID == rrid) permissionList)  )
                                                )  (DL.filter (\(ruid,_,_) -> ruid == userid && (case rid of
                                                                                                        Just _ -> True
                                                                                                        Nothing -> False)
                                                                                                    ) roleList)
                                            ) 
                                        ) rolePermissions
```

i want this function of type Map User ([Permission], Map Role [Permission]) but im getting it as  Map User ([Permission], [Map Role [Permission]])

here is the code with data http://lpaste.net/362797

(i had posted this earliar but then deleted and corrected it as some people suggested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t3 userid = DL.nub $` immediately says that what you receive in `t3` is a list, because its signature is `[A] -> [A]`. Now look at the second line, where `t3` goes.

Things would be much simpler if you split your large function into a few smaller, *descriptively named*  functions. At least you could `:t thatFunctionName` to check types as you go, if you don't want to write them explicitly.